# Webrtc Audio Autoplaying On Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, webrtc

I have webrtc working in a webapp but it seems that when connections are established between Chrome browsers the audio is not played, while video is. This however doesn't apply to Mozilla users. So...

Chrome user 1 -> Chrome user 2 = plays video but not audo 
Chrome user 1 -> Mozilla user 1 = plays audio and video 
Mozilla user 1 -> Chrome user 1 = plays audio and video 
Mozilla user 1 - Chrome user 2 = plays audio and video 
Mozilla user 1 -> Mozilla user 2 = plays audio and video

Based on this I'm confused as to why this would happen as there doesn't seem to be problems with the stream (both audio and video tracks are sent through and both are enabled). This is my video tag that plays it afterwards

```
<video src={{stream.src}} id={{stream.id}} autoplay></video>
```

Comment: `<video src={{stream.src}} id={{stream.id}} autoplay controls ></video>`
open chrome://webrtc-internals/ and see the audio input/output levels in Stats graphs for ssrc_XXXX_send/recv (audio)

Comment: @Ajay Confirms the problem. The client that doesn't hear audio has a ssrc_XXXX_recv (video) and a ssrc_XXXX_recv. But no specific ssrc_XXXX_recv (audio). The other client client has a ssrc_XXXX_send (audio) with input level staying at 0, and a ssrc_XXXX_send (video) with what seems to be functional input levels. Only happens with Chrome

Comment: Need to look into the offer and answer sdp's, share your offer&answer with pastebin.

Comment: Ended up doing some research and finding that the Mac microphone has problems with Webrtc in Chrome sometimes and one of the solutions was to reset the PRAM. It worked for me. Details found here https://www.onlinemictest.com/microphone-settings/mac-os-x/

Answer (score 0):

When doing the communication test of "Chrome user 1 -> Chrome user 2" , can you please check any error from both browsers ? You can do this by right click and select Inspect button from both browsers when communicate is on. If there's any error can you please post it to here?

Comment: No errors or problems. The entire stream is received and the video plays, but the audio doesn't